# Debugging a case statement in a C program (a clause won't run)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Time
{
int hrs;               // private members of lass Time
int mins;            // private members of lass Time
int secs;           // private members of lass Time

public:
void gettime(int h,int m, int s)
  {
   hrs=h;
   mins=m;
   secs=s;
  }

void convert(Time tm,char ch);


};

void Time::convert(Time tm, char ch)   // to display time in hours or PM/AM format as per choice
 { switch (ch)
    {
     case 'h': cout << "Time in hours: " << tm.hrs << ":" << tm.mins << ":" << tm.secs;
               break;
     case 'p': cout << "Time in am/pm: " << ((tm.hrs>12)? (tm.hrs-12) : tm.hrs) << ":" << tm.mins << ":" << tm.secs;
               cout << ((tm.hrs>12)? "pm" : "am");
               break;
     default : cout <<  "wrong choice !";

    };                // switch ends here
 }                    // convert function ends here

 int main()
 {
  Time t1,t2;                       // created two Time objects
  int c;
  cout << "In which format would you like to see the time\n";
  cout << "choose 'h' for hours and 'p' in am/pm: ";
  cin >> c;
  t1.gettime(15,45,30);   
  t2.convert(t1,c);

  return 0;

 }
```

When I run this code in codeblocks, it does not display time. I've checked with both choices h and p.

Below is the output

```
output:
In which format would you like to see the time
choose 'h' for hours and 'p' in am/pm:h
wrong choice !
Process returned 0 ()0x0   execution time : 4.131 s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

It is skipping "case 1" going to default. I got this code from c++ book written by sumita arora.

Comment: You are passing `int c` to a `char`. Use `char c`

Comment: `int c` but `h` or `p` shall be input? That will only work if you input "112" or "104". If you want character input, then make `c` a `char`.

Comment: Raise the compiler's warning level and you should get warnings for example when you call `convert` with an `int` where a `char` is expected.

Comment: @WernerHenze [Nah](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7746fa77fa6435c)

Comment: `void convert(Time tm,char ch);` seems to be an unusual signature. Why does it take a Time object by value when the current Time object should probably be used?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings "warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'int' to 'char', possible loss of data" on MSVC starting at warning level 2. BTW, you could add `-Wextra`, but that does not help getting a warning on g++.

Comment: @WernerHenze Narrowing conversion warnings are hit and miss

Comment: BTW, you have a **C++** program, not as your title says.  The C language doesn't support `namespace`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int c;
// ...
cin >> c;
// ...
t2.convert(t1,c);
```

You read an `int` not a character. If you type `'h'` then `cin >> c` will fail, becaue `'h'` is not an integer, `c` will be set to `0` (since C++11, before it was left uninitialized) and there is no way the implicit conversion from the `int c` to `char` will yield `'h'` or `'q'` (unless you enter the corresponding ascii code for `'h'` or `'q'`). If you want to read a character, then read a character. And make sure to check if input failed:

```
char c;
if (std::cin >> c) {
     // do something with c
} else {
     std::cout << "invalid input";
}
```

Comment: ooh how my eyes missed it I investigated my code for 1 hour even then I could not able to find this issue. Thank you so much for correcting me. god bless you.

Comment: @AshokDewan use a debugger next time. If you had taken a look at the value of `ch` inside the method you would have realized that there is something wrong